# EWS getting of MimeContent async request takes too long to respond in Outlook Desktop

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am working with Outlook Plugin and i used Exchange Web Service to support lower versions of Outlook.
I have to fetch the mime content of the email and upload it somewhere. I am using this code to fetch the mime content but when using Outlook Desktop it took aroung 3 mins for 400kb file to load. Do you have any suggestions or resolutions on this? I can't use Graph API and Rest API because some users are using old Exchange Server.

```
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
    '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
    '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
    '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"' +
    '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '  <soap:Header>' +
    '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0"/>' +
    '  </soap:Header>' +
    '  <soap:Body>' +
    '   <m:GetItem>' +
    '       <m:ItemShape>' +
    '           <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>' +
    '           <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>' +
    '           <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>' +
    '       </m:ItemShape>' +
    '       <m:ItemIds>' +
    '           <t:ItemId Id="' + emailItemID + '" />' +
    '       </m:ItemIds>' +
    '   </m:GetItem>' +
    '  </soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>'
```

Comment: I use the same EWS request and it was realatively fast. The problem I faced was that if the attachment was bigger then 6-7 mB, IE11 instance Outlook is throwing a SyntaxError (which in reallity is an OOM because of a bug in IE11 when trying to read the response xml that exeeds x-amout of lines). As workaround I created a simple c# webapi server running on IIS to which I send the exchangeToken and attachmendIds and the server uses [EWS Managed API 2.0](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api).

Comment: 3 mins for 400kb doesn't sound correct and doesn't sound like a code issue more and issue with the server or infrastructure, have you tried testing this outside of the addin maybe use the EWSEditor or write a simple console app

Comment: @Lumpenstein The issue i am having only appears in Outlook Desktop. Outlook Web Access works pretty fast using the same email and the same request. I will try to survey EWS Managed API if its applicable on my use case.

Comment: @GlenScales Thanks for reminding me to try this. Based from my testing on EWSEditor, it only takes few seconds using the same request. It also responds fast using Outlook Web Access unlike the Outlook Desktop App.
The result is this one. I supposed this is an Outlook Desktop issue but i need to do workaround if so.
\n\n
Start: 15/03/2020 8:44:57 PM  End: 15/03/2020 8:45:10 PM  Timespan: 00:00:13.20:
ResponseStatusCode: OK
ResponseCodeNumber: 200

Comment: For clarification: I assume you're using `makeEwsRequestAsync` for this call? If so, what versions of Outlook for Win32 and Exchange are you testing against?